About acceleration of the convergence of a sequence over another one.
Assume $u_n\to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, that is $\|u_n-u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to 0$.  Let $\phi_\delta=\delta^{-d} \phi(\frac{x}{\delta})$ be a nice molifier $\phi\in C_c^\infty{B_1(0)}$, $0\leq \phi\leq 1$ and $\int \phi=1$.
There are given  functionals satisfying the following property:
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{\delta\to0^+}F_n(u_n*\phi_\delta-u_n)=0 \quad \text{for each $n\geq 1$}. 
\end{align*}
This implies that there is $\delta_n\to 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta\to0^+} F_n(u_n*\phi_{\delta_n}-u_n)=0 \quad \text{for each $n\geq 1$}. 
\end{align*}
Question Is it possible to construct two subsequences $\theta(n)$ and $\tau(n)$ (eventually $\theta(n)=\tau(n)$)  such that
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}F_{\theta(n)}(u_{\theta(n)}*\phi_{\delta_{\tau(n)}}-u_{\theta(n)})=0\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|u_{\theta(n)} -u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\delta_{\tau(n)}}=0\\
\end{align*}
Another way to ask the question: Is can we find a subsequence $\theta(n)$ and sequence $\delta'_n\to 0$ such that
In word is it possible to accelerate the convergence $\|u_{\theta(n)} -u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to 0$ over the sequence $\delta_n$
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}F_{\theta(n)}(u_{\theta(n)}*\phi_{\delta'_{n}}-u_{\theta(n)})=0\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|u_{\theta(n)} -u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\delta'_{n}}=0
\end{align*}
